# RabbitMQ consumer crash and consumer-count

Tags: rabbitmq

If a consumer of a RabbitMQ crashes, with no graceful disconnection, will a subsequent [declare-ok](http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html#queue.declare-ok) request fired several milliseconds later report a diminished consumer-count? Or is there an amount of time that needs to pass before the reported number will change?

Comment: It's all about race conditions problem. Millisecond earlier, millisecond later - who cares?

Answer (score 0):

`declare-ok` count all known consumers regardless their actual state.

See, in fact, some time after connection get dangled it still marked as alive (exact time depends on OS settings and whether do you use [heartbeats](https://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html) and whether there are any network operation over that connection). In RabbitMQ management panel you may see connection and it channels with consumer tags listed some time after connection died.